# Why typescript allows referencing/assigning a readonly type/property by mutable type?

Tags: typescript, readonly

Why doesn't typescript enforce readonly keyword and prevent us from passing a read only property into non readonly one, that's defy the point

````
let foo: {
    readonly bar: number;
} = {
        bar: 123
    };

function iMutateFoo(foo: { bar: number }) {
    foo.bar = 456;
}

iMutateFoo(foo); // The foo argument is aliased by the foo parameter
console.log(foo.bar); // 456!```
````

Comment: I wrote an ESLint rule to prevent this scenario: https://github.com/danielnixon/eslint-plugin-total-functions#total-functionsno-unsafe-assignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known behavior, tracked at [microsoft/TypeScript#13347](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347) whose surprising effects inspired an issue originally titled ["readonly modifiers are a joke"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13002#event-916346948).  The short answer to the question is "it would have broken backwards compatibility when `readonly` was introduced".  The long answer comes from the following comment:

@ahelsberg [said](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6532#issuecomment-174356151):

> In order to ensure backwards compatibility, the `readonly` modifier doesn't affect subtype and assignability type relationships of the containing type (but of course it affects assignments to individual properties).
>
> Consider the following code:
>
> ```
> interface ArrayLike<T> {
>   length: number;
>   [index: number]: T;
> }
>
> function foo(array: ArrayLike<string>) {
>    // Doesn't mutate array
> }
>
> var s = "hello";
> var a = ["one", "two", "three"];
> foo(s);  // s has readonly length and index signature
> foo(a);
> ```
>
> In existing TypeScript code there is no way to indicate if a particular property is intended to be read-only or mutable. In the code above, `foo` doesn't mutate the array it is passed, but there is nothing in the code that says it can't. However, now that we've added a `readonly` modifier to the `length` property and the index signature in the `String` interface (because they really are read-only), the `foo(s)` call above would be an error if we said that a `readonly` property is incompatible with a property without `readonly`. Specifically, we can't interpret the absence of a `readonly` modifier to mean read-write, we can only say that we don't know. So, if an interface differs from another interface only in the `readonly` modifiers on its properties, we have to say that the two interfaces are compatible. Anything else would be a massive breaking change.

So there you have it.  If you want to show your support for a fix to this, you might want to head over to that [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347) and give it a  or describe your use case if it's compelling and not already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The `readonly` keyword is only a ts-compiler check. With that said you are telling the compiler that the mutate function accepts a non-readonly parameter.

However if you actually type it correctly, the compiler will complain e.g.

```
type test = { readonly bar: number };

let foo: test = {
    bar: 123
};

function iMutateFoo(foo: test) {
    foo.bar = 456; // error
}
```

Comment: my point is that you can't guarantee immutability downstream, although they could enforce readonly compile time check as part of type information checking, which I'm asking why they haven't done so