# Why property in class is not read only (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, readonly

Why property name in class PeronsImpl is not read only and we can reassign it the object created ?

```
    interface Person {
    readonly name: string;
}

interface Greeting extends Person {
    greet(message: string): void;
}

class PersonImpl implements Greeting {
   name: string;
   age = 30;
   constructor(n: string) {
      this.name = n;
   }
   greet(message: string) {
      console.log(message + ' ' + this.name);
   }
} 

let pers = new PersonImpl("maha");
console.log(`pers : ${pers.name}`);
pers.name = "maha2";
pers.greet("hello"); //hello maha2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two parts to this:  Class properties do not inherit typings from the classes or interfaces they extend; and readonly properties are mutually assignable to and from mutable properties.

---

**Class properties do not inherit typings from the classes or interfaces they extend**

When you write `class Foo implements Bar {...}`, the compiler does not use `Bar` to infer the types of any of `Foo`'s properties.  It behaves as if `implements Bar` were not present, infers all the types of `Foo`'s properties, and then just *checks* against `Bar`.  For example:

```
interface Foo {
  x: 0 | 1;
}

class Bar implements Foo {
  x = 1; // error! x is inferred as number, not 0 | 1 
}
```

This is an error because `class Bar { x = 1 }` would infer just `number` for `x`, and since `number` is not assignable to `0 | 1`, it's an error.  This behavior is surprising and unpleasant to lots of folks, and there are quite a few GitHub issues requesting something better here.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#10570](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570) for one particularly longstanding open issue about it.

That means the `name` property of `PersonImpl` is of type `string`, and is not `readonly`:

```
class PersonImpl implements Greeting {
  name: string; // string, not readonly string
  //...
}
```

---

**Readonly properties are mutually assignable to and from mutable properties**

The second issue is that types which differ only by the `readonly`-ness of their properties are considered to be mutually compatible by the compiler.  You can assign a `{readonly x: string}` to an `{x: string}` and vice versa without error.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168250/2887218) for more information about why that is, or see [microsoft/TypeScript#13347](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347) for a feature request asking this to be changed.

So that means the compiler does not issue an error that `PersonImpl`'s `name` property is mutable while `Greeting`'s is `readonly`.  Those types are not considered incompatible.

---

Put those together, and you get the weirdness you see here. You might happily assume that `PersonImpl`'s `name` property is `readonly`, and then get confused when you are allowed to assign a value to it.

The fix here is the general workaround to the class inherited typing issue; give *explicit type annotations and modifiers* to your properties:

```
class PersonImpl implements Greeting {
  readonly name: string; // annotate with readonly
  /* ... */
}

let pers = new PersonImpl("maha");
pers.name = "maha2"; // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-WaHThyNYbW632eR3k8T+NDAYjIn6cHjNFUgNXbMSSPZycrdU4-SLROIgRLnYaXUY3GO6OAgZ5gOCQGu-IZyoGEukgCFQmFwlsIpFnWnIQUOvFykAjon94NVNncP5Um6z-ujkLGlnbv78vm8gUYpcyV3z4nrgpEKXIe0rxXK1qqraaxN6+9kDBMcGQgJlT3NWUbTtYIPQgZ1APdVMvX-f121qKAXCgH4g1JMMIyjUU7jjZlkFQzxmCAA)

Answer (score 1):

> Why property name in class PeronsImpl is not read only...

Because it is typecast as `PersonImpl` and *not* `Person`. If you want `name` as readonly you must also make it so in the implementation *or* variable `pers` should be defined as type `Person`.

```
class PersonImpl implements Greeting {
   readonly name: string; // <-- added readonly
   age = 30;
   constructor(n: string) {
      this.name = n;
   }
```

or specify type

```
let pers:Person = new PersonImpl("maha"); // <-- added :Person
```

Comment: I think OP question is why the `implements` clause doesn't force `name` property to be `readonly`.

Comment: @MinusFour - I believe the OP is asking why you can reassign the value based on `...and we can reassign it the object created`, I did not read anything about a possible TS error on building/transpiling. That is just my interpretation though.

Comment: Maybe so but question title asks why the class property isn't read only.